# How much memory is allocated to call stack?

Tags: c++, memory-management, segmentation-fault, callstack

Previously I had seen assembly of many functions in C++. In gcc, all of them start with these instructions:

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
sub     rsp, <X>  ; <X> is size of frame
```

I know that these instructions store the frame pointer of previous function and then sets up a frame for current function. But here, assembly is neither asking for mapping memory (like malloc) and nor it is checking weather the memory pointed by `rbp` is allocated to the process.

So it assumes that startup code has mapped enough memory for the entire depth of call stack. So exactly how much memory is allocated for call stack? How does startup code can know the maximum depth of call stack?

It also means that, I can access array out of bound for a long distance since although it is not in current frame, it mapped to the process. So I wrote this code:

```
int main() {
    int arr[3] = {};
    printf("%d", arr[900]);
}
```

This is exiting with `SIGSEGV` when index is 900. But surprisingly not when index is 901. Similarly, it is exiting with `SIGSEGV` for some random indices and not for some. This behavior was observed when compiled with gcc-x86-64-11.2 in [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:8,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:8),source:%27//+Type+your+code+here,+or+load+an+example.%0A%0A%23include%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++int+arr%5B3%5D+%3D+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++printf(%22%25d%22,+arr%5B902%5D)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.550039915813926,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.44996008418609,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:60.54628224582701,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:39.45371775417299,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Comment: *So exactly how much memory is allocated for call stack?* That is controlled by your compiler.  For your array indexing, you have UB, so any result is possible.

Comment: The segmentation fault you are observing on compiler explorer is not deterministic based on the index chosen. It is just a random effect, probably related to whether or not you happen to cross a stack page. Compiler explorer caches the result from some given code, but if you add some irrelevant whitespace it will compile and run again. You will get random results.

Comment: The stack growing direction isn't specified anywhere, so there need not be any stack memory at `arr[900]` regardless of the stack size.

Comment: Note that your question has no C++ in it, and that "the right way to do it" in C++ is different from that in C. Generally speaking, in virtually all the cases a question tagged *both* C *and* C++ is lacking focus, because actually it's two (disjunct) questions. The only reason I am not taking the C++ tag out of it is that there is already a question (partially) addressing C++.

Comment: @DevSolar extremely sorry for that, I was just bit hurry. But anyway I feel this question in particular is language independent. (implementation dependant)

Comment: Be aware that there is in no way any guarantee that a misguided memory access is caught *at all*, SIGSEGV or otherwise... SIGSEGV is a safety feature by *some* operating systems. Invoking undefined behavior has, well, *undefined* results... ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How does startup code can know the maximum depth of call stack?

It doesn't.

In most common implementation, the size of the stack is constant.

If the program exceeds the constant sized stack, that is called a stack overflow. This is why you must avoid creating large objects (which are typically, but not necessarily, arrays) in automatic storage, and why you must avoid recursion with linear depth (such as recursive linked list algorithms).

> So exactly how much memory is allocated for call stack?

On most desktop/server systems it's configurable, and defaults to one to few megabytes. It can be much less on embedded systems.

> This is exiting with SIGSEGV when index is 900. But surprisingly not when index is 901.

In both cases, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> Is it possible to know the allocated stack size?

Yes. You can read the documentation of the target system. If you intend to write a portable program, then you must assume the minimum of all target systems. For desktop/server, 1 megabyte that I mentioned is reasonable.

There is no *standard* way to acquire the size within C++.

Comment: I don't like advertising against "creating large objects in automatic storage" for C++, because that can lead -- especially with beginners -- to very poor programming practices. C++ containers in automatic storage usually have a very, very small footprint, because they manage their data on the heap automatically. Beginners might not realize that, and take your argument to start to `new std::string` because they want to avoid putting strings "in automatic storage". This might be OK for C, but in C++ having objects in automatic storage is usually the *right* thing to do...

Comment: @DevSolar Judging by the amount of "halp halp seg fault" questions we get on this site, I disagree. A significant amount of these are stack overflows. Also, there are some C++ libs that allocate _everything_ on the heap regardless of it's size. The good old C++ Builder VCL library for example. (Which pre-dates correctly implemented smart pointers in C++ by some 15 years or so.)

Comment: @DevSolar `C++ containers in automatic storage usually have a very, very small footprint,` Hence "Don't create **large** objects in automatic storage" doesn't apply to them. `int automatic[1 << 99999];` is a much more serious problem than unnecessary dynamic allocation. There's no difference between C and C++ in this regard. Beginners have much to learn and one sentence cannot cover all of it.

Comment: @eerorika: Well, I consider `int[]` to be a purely C construct that every C++ programmer with some self-esteem should endeavor to kill with extreme prejudice.

Comment: @Lundin: But how many of these "halp halp seg fault" questions *arise because of C constructs and procedures ill-advisedly being transported to C++*? Use `std::vector< int >` in automatic storage instead of using `int []` *at all*. We -- as SO's C++ community -- still cater far too much for "poor C called C++ because I use `std::cout` and use g++ instead of gcc". Those are two very different languages, with two very different approaches to how things are "done right".

Comment: @DevSolar You can substitute `int[]` with `std::array<int, (1 << 30)> automatic;` if you so prefer. It makes little difference. The size is a problem in both cases. (I should have used a smaller size in the first place since the point was to be example of large object rather than integer overflow).

Comment: @eerorika How do I / Is it possible to know the allocated stack size? Does it depend on platform or compiler/startup/environment?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB See edit.

Comment: @DevSolar Not everyone codes for a PC though, there might be no heap present where std::vector can bloat away. A lot of bad practices in C++ come from C++ tradition and bad language design - Stroustrup stubbornly refused to acknowledge that std::vector wasn't an universal array type and that it was far slower than plain C arrays up to std::array was introduced... and then I don't even think he was involved much in the creation of STL.

Comment: @eerorika: And that is why I was talking about using `std::vector` instead of `int[]`, exactly *because* it makes a difference. The use case for `std::array` is a rather niche one, and I wouldn't inflict it on students until much later on. Unless stated otherwise the go-to container should be `std::vector`.

Comment: @Lundin: See above. Using `std::array` is in most cases just premature optimization, and quite often motivated by a lack of understanding of `std::vector`. And we're not talking to an aspiring embedded programming wizard here, but a beginner with the language. KISS.

Comment: @DevSolar You don't have to use `std::vector` specifically. What you must do is use dynamic storage for large objects, because of limited size available for automatic storage. `std::vector` uses dynamic storage, so it's one option. `int automatic[1 << 30];` isn't wrong (in this regard) "because it's C". It's wrong because it's too large for automatic storage, and same applies to other large objects including those that are in the standard library. And same applies equally to C.

Comment: @eerorika: My point being that you are assuming OP *knows* that `std::vector` uses dynamic storage and hence does not fall under your warning against large objects in automatic storage.

Comment: @DevSolar I don't see how that point is relevant. There are many other templates that also use dynamic storage. I cannot list all of them in my answer, and I don't see a reason to mention any one of them in particular.

Comment: {Sigh.} You *don't* see the irony in the two discussions I am having with you and Lundin here? You say "of course containers use dynamic storage, why should I point that out special", and Lundin points out the one that doesn't because he considers `std::vector` to be "bloat"...

Comment: @DevSolar My point isn't that "of course" containers use dynamic storage. After all, `std::array` is in some contexts considered to be a "container". My point is that my answer to the question "how large is stack" contains a sidenote about how the size of stack affects "when to avoid automatic storage" which is a separate discussion from "what are some examples of how automatic storage could be avoided (vector being such example)" which I consider to be outside the scope of my answer.